# overriding system properties in maven

Tags: java, maven, logback, system-properties, maven-profiles

I have a web application with a couple of profiles - for production and for local testing; 
build is executed with maven;
logback is used for logging

so some of logs write to files - the problem is:
in production we use tomcat and CATALINA_HOME is set on server, 
but locally we often use jetty, so tomcat may even not be configured

so in prod i want to write log in file this way:
${catalina.home}/logs/profiler.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log

how do I set maven override this ${catalina.home} property

1. how do i set it from maven (do i need system properties or just maven properties)
2. may i make it conditional?  (if it is not set on the local system then use the property
   defined in #1)

thanks a lot!
tatiana.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a maven `property`, say `log.dir` and set it to appropriate values in each `profile`.

Say,

```
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <log.dir>${catalina.home}/...</log.dirv>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```